# Unresolved inclusion: <stdio.h> (windows 8)

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded eclipse for c/c++ but when I writes `#include <stdio.h>` for example I got an error `Unresolved inclusion: <stdio.h>`.

I see on the Internet some answers about similar problems but they didn't work in my case.
When I goes to `Properties -> Paths and symbols`, I don't have any thing on "includes".

Comment: you mean `#include <stdio.h>` ?

Comment: Did you try `#include <cstdio>` (which is a C++ wrapper for the C library)?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  This is one area where the languages are different.  The C++ language does not have the library (header) `stdio.h`.  The C language doesn't have the library `cstdio`.

Comment: Yes, I mean to #include <stdio.h>. but it doesn't matter because it doesnt reconized any library such as #include <stdlib.h> or #include <cstdio.h>

Comment: Probably not going to help, but you should look into [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329). (Tiny hint to a tiny problem: `cstdio` is different from `cstdio.h`.)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not come with a C or C++ compiler. You need to install one separately. The compiler installation will then provide the standard library headers like `<stdio.h>`.

Popular C/C++ compilers for Windows include [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) and [Visual C++](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/cplusplus/).